# "Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now" when updating to php8.2.5 from older PHP version

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a mysqli wrapper from PHP 5 written years ago, but it gives an error when trying to run on PHP 8.2.5. I have tried everything. Here are the two main functions:

```
global $db_obj, $db_driver;

function db_login() {
    global $db_obj;
    $res = @$db_obj->connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    if($res == false) {
        display_error("Could not connect to database.");
    }
    db_maybe_handle_error();
    db_select_db();
    db_set_charset();
}

function db_select_db($db = DB_NAME) {
    global $db_obj;
    @$db_obj->select_db($db);
    db_maybe_handle_error();
}

function db_set_charset($charset = 'utf8') {
    global $db_obj;
    @$db_obj->set_charset($charset);
    db_maybe_handle_error();
}

function db_error() {
    global $db_obj;
    return $db_obj->error();
}

function db_maybe_handle_error($r = null, $extra_info = "") {
    $e = db_error();
    if($e != '') {
       echo "mysql error: " . $e . " " . hsc($extra_info);
    }
    return $r;
}

function db_query($q) {

    $num_args = func_num_args();
    $arg_list = func_get_args();
    $r = null;

    global $db_obj;

    if($num_args > 1) {
        $stmt = $db_obj->stmt_init();
        if($stmt->prepare($q)) {
            $types = "";
            $refArr = array("");
            for($i = 1; $i < $num_args; $i++) {
                $type = gettype($arg_list[$i]) === "integer" ? "i" : "s";
                //$stmt->bind_param($type, $arg_list[$i]);
                // PHP <=5.2: Remove the ampersand
                // See http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php
                $refArr[] = &$arg_list[$i];
                $types .= $type;
            }
            $refArr[0] = $types;
            $ref = new ReflectionClass('mysqli_stmt');
            $method = $ref->getMethod("bind_param");
            $method->invokeArgs($stmt, $refArr);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();
            $r = $stmt;
        } else {
            db_maybe_handle_error(null, $q);
        }
    } else {
        $r = @$db_obj->query($q);
    }

    db_maybe_handle_error(null, $q);

    return $r;
}

function db_fetch($res, $use_numerical_indices = null) {
    global $db_obj;

    $use_numerical_indices = $use_numerical_indices === true ||
        ($use_numerical_indices === null && DB_DEFAULT_USE_NUMERICAL_INDEXES);

    if(is_array($res)) {
        return array_shift($res);
    }

    if($res instanceof mysqli_stmt) {
        $res->store_result();
        //$res->get_result();
        $variables = array();
        $data = array();
        $meta = $res->result_metadata();

        while($field = $meta->fetch_field()) {
            $variables[] = &$data[$field->name];
        }

        call_user_func_array(array($res, 'bind_result'), $variables);

        if(!$res->fetch()) {
            $res->close();
            return null;
        }
        $array = array();
        $i = 0;
        foreach($data as $k => $v) {
            $array[$k] = $v;
            if($use_numerical_indices) {
                $array[$i] = $v;
            }
            $i++;
        }
        db_maybe_handle_error($array);
    }
    $result_type = $use_numerical_indices ? $db_obj->BOTH : $db_obj->ASSOC;
    $r = @$db_obj->fetch_array($res, $result_type);
    return db_maybe_handle_error($r);
}

function db_num_rows($res) {
    global $db_obj;
    if(is_array($res)) {
        return count($res);
    }
    if($res instanceof mysqli_stmt) {
        return mysqli_stmt_num_rows($res);
    }
    $r = @$db_obj->num_rows($res);
    return db_maybe_handle_error($r);
}

function db_insert_id() {
    global $db_obj;
    $r = @$db_obj->insert_id();
    return db_maybe_handle_error($r);
}
```

And to get a row, a standard query can be done with:

```
$row = db_fetch(db_query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id=? LIMIT 1", $id));
```

The line with `store_result()` (in the `db_fetch` function) gives this error:

> Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

I have tried just about everything, including trying to add in `$stmt->free_result()` and `$stmt->close()` into different parts of the code segment.

The issue is that I'm specifically requesting help with rewriting this code segment using `$stmt->free_request()` or and `$stmt->close()` so that minimum code changes happen and can keep things in place as much as possible. Where would those go in the `db_query` and `db_fetch` functions?

Comment: What's the point of `ReflectionClass`? Is this something from the days of PHP 5? It seems like you should have removed that when migrating to PHP 7.

Comment: You have so much redundant code here. Most of the code needs to be removed. If you are using PHP 8.2 then you can simplify it  by using functions like `execute_query()` which will reduce this code by a factor of 10.

Comment: I don't think this error has anything to do with upgrading to PHP 8. The error is coming from MySQL, not PHP.

Comment: It's really difficult to read this code. You don't specify types, you have manual error checking (probably from the old mysql_* extension), your function names are not very clear, the code starts with strange global declaration (is this wrapped in another function?), you are using globals instead of passing values via parameters. If there is an error here, it will be difficult to find it.

Comment: I am giving you a harsh but kind advice: remove all of this code. There's nothing worth salvaging here. Instead either switch to PDO or if that is too much work, use `mysqli_execute_query()`. Make sure you enable mysqli error reporting (it is enabled by default but make sure you don't silence it). This code looks like it's doing a lot but it doesn't do anything useful. Just make your life easier and remove all of it. Trust me.

Comment: @Dharman realize it looks like a lot of nonsense code and some is (and at some point should prob rewrite into a class) but it's important to keep structure/ flow the way it is bc there are more functions and stuff that didn't share to use them, etc. Please let me know if you have an idea on this, and thanks for the comments already

Comment: You really should remove `db_maybe_handle_error()` as a priority. This function is actually dangerous as it could expose sensitive information to your end users.

Comment: And please put on your todo list to replace the old deprecated `utf8` charset with the correct `utf8mb4`.

Answer (score 1):

The error you got means that you are trying to execute mysqli functions (and in turn MySQL commands) out of order. MySQL will reply with this error when it gets a command that is not expected at this moment.

You do not add `free_result()` or `close()` anywhere in your code. A properly structure code should NOT have any of these functions. They are only there to prevent memory leaks in spaghetti code.

To fix the error you must make sure that the operations are executed in the right sequence. But this code is way too messy to make heads or tails of it. You must rewrite it!

Try something simple like this:

```
function db_query($q, $params = []): mysqli_result
{
    global $db_obj; // DO NOT USE GLOBALS!!!

    return $db_obj->execute_query($q, $params);
}

function db_fetch(mysqli_result $res, $use_numerical_indices = null)
{
    $use_numerical_indices = $use_numerical_indices === true ||
        ($use_numerical_indices === null && DB_DEFAULT_USE_NUMERICAL_INDEXES);

    $result_type = $use_numerical_indices ? MYSQLI_NUM : MYSQLI_ASSOC;
    return $res->fetch_array($result_type);
}
```

Other functions need to be trimmed in a similar manner.

The actual problem is that you are calling `store_result()` twice. The easiest fix would be to remove one of them. But which one you remove is a mystery as this code doesn't make it clear which one, if any, is actually necessary. You could probably remove both, but then `db_num_rows` will not work.